# Format text with more than one parameter in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, format

Is it possible to directly format a text which has many place holders in message resource in struts 2?

As an example, consider below keys, which should produce **Transfer2000USDFromBobToMike**

```
#resources.properties
filename=Transfer{0}From{1}To{2}

#resources_fa_IR.properties (consider this is correct translation in Persian!) 
filename={انتقال{0} از {1} به {2
```

In the action I want to invoke something like this (which is not valid!!):

```
getText("filename", amount,sourceAccount,destincationAccount);
```

I know that I can first get the `filename` and then use java [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

On the other hand I find examples which format the messages directly. As you know this is valid

```
message properties
format.money = {0,number,\u00A4##0.00}

jsp
<s:text name="%{getText('format.money',{amount})}" />
```

Can I use the above solution (shortcut) to format the `filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your parameters as array or as list, because `getText` method is overloaded like that:

```
getText(String key, String[] args)
```

and

```
getText(String aTextName, List<?> args)
```

For example:

```
getText("filename", new String[] { amount, sourceAccount, destincationAccount });
```